# Xamarin android splash screen. Disallow input

Tags: android, input, xamarin, splash-screen

Created splash screen for Xamarin android application.

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", //Indicates the theme to use for this activity
         MainLauncher = true, //Set it as boot activity
         NoHistory = true)]
public class SplashActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
    }
}
```

Nothing special. But there is a problem: If I touch, swipe a screen while splash screen is showing then all these input events start to execute (press button for example) after splash screen is gone. Can I somehow prevent it? Why "main" activity catches events of splash screen activity?

Answer (score 0):

You start `MainActivity` in `onCreate()` of `SplashActivity` without any delay. Put some delay to start MainActivity.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new Handler().PostDelayed(new Action(HandleAction), 3000);//Splash shows for 3 seconds
}

void HandleAction()
{
    StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
}
```

Comment: It partially solves the problem but I don't think it is the proper solution because we can't know exactly time app loads libraries and another problem that if app could start for less than 3 seconds(when cached) it wouldn't because of delay

Comment: Normally a splashscreen is a type of Branding. Most of the times the duration will be the hardcoded time. Unless you have something to fetch from network or any other code to work, this is the common approach. during network operations, some apps will wait for the service to finish to start the new activity. Its upto the requirement.

Comment: Also if there is no delay when starting a new activity, then there is no need of a splashscreen at all since the user won't get any idea of what just showed as Splash.

Comment: Without a delay my splash screen is showing about 4-5 seconds or 1-2 when app is cached. This splash screen was created to be showed instead of a black screen for these 4-5 seconds while android loads libraries for the app. So without delay app won't start immediately.